# Python, can i get a return true or false, if a file TYPE exists or not?

Tags: python

ive read through the path.exists() and path.isdir() questions on here, but none that ive found so far, deal with check if a particular file type exists in a directory or not... maybe im not searching the correct terms for this.

basically, i want to poll a set of folders to see if there are txt files there... if they are there, i will want to run a string of pexpect commands (each with different usernames/passwords) to put *.txt them to a remote server location. I have my put and get pexpect script working already.

I tried using a wildcard such as this, but of course no such luck.

```
>>> print(os.path.exists("/mnt/path/to/shared/folder/*.txt"))
False
```

instead of having 15 cron jobs, doing a blind put *.txt every 5 minutes, i'd like to run just one script that checks all folder locations.  if txt files exists = true (then do pexpect job) if false, go to next folder path and check if txt files exist = true (then do pexpect job) ect....

glob seems to be the ticket. I tested it with this:

```
    import glob

if next(glob.iglob("/path/to/files/*.txt"), None):
   print "there are txt files" # there are text files
else:
    print "there are no text files"
```

$ python check.py

there are txt files

Comment: if glob.glob, and if next(glob.iglob), both work just great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html).

```
import glob

if glob.glob("/mnt/path/to/shared/folder/*.txt"):
    # there are text files
else:
    # No text files
```

Glob will return a list of files matching the wildcard-accessible path. If there are no files, it will return an empty list. This is really just `os.listdir` and `fnmatch.filter` together.

If memory is an issue, use `glob.iglob` as 200OK suggests in the comments:

```
import glob

if next(glob.iglob("/mnt/path/to/shared/folder/*.txt"), None):
    # there are text files
else:
    # No text files
```

`iglob` builds an iterator instead of a list, which is massively more memory-saving.

Comment: `if next(glog.iglob(...), None)`

Comment: Just `iglob` would be... yeah, what @200OK wrote. Except that it makes me think of [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7976309/91757) in which a reason is given why you can't just write `if glob.iglob(..):`. :-/

Answer (score 1):

If your problem specifically is to find files with particular criteria, consider opening/reading a pipe to the program [find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find).

As in:

```
find dir1 dir2 dir3 -name "*.txt"
```

That program has dozens of options for filtering based on the type of file (symlink, etc) and should give you a lot of flexibility that might be easier than writing it yourself with various python libraries.

Comment: There are serious problems with trying to parse the output of the `find` command that make it unlikely to be a better option than simply doing everything in-Python.

Comment: What would those problems be?  By default, find outputs one filename per line

Comment: @chepner I'm still very new to *nix, but I can't imagine parsing a binary "yes there are files" or "no there aren't files" to be very hard.

Comment: @FrobberOfBits see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls

Comment: @chepner that answer has lots of reasons why it's a bad idea to try to parse file attributes out of the output of **ls** - but I'm talking about reading one filename per line from **find**.  The only problem I can see is if OP's filenames include \n in them.  Aside from being unlikely, using the functionality of find seems superior than trying to implement your own filter code for more advanced requirements (i.e. only return symlinks newer than a certain date)