# map function run into infinite loop in 3.X

Tags: python, dictionary, iterator

I'm currently studying iteration in python.

I have encountered the following code.

```
def myzip(*args):
    iters = map(iter, args)
    while iters:
        res = [next(i) for i in iters]
        print(res)
        yield tuple(res)

list(myzip('abc', '1mnop'))
```

When I run the code in 3.X, the code runs into a infinite loop, and prints

```
['a', '1']
[]
[]
[]
...
```

The explanation I got from the author is

> 3.X map returns a one-shot iterable object instead of a list as in 2.X. In 3.X, as soon as we’ve run the list comprehension inside the loop once, iters will be exhausted but still True (and res will be [])
>   forever.

But I am still struggling to understand what is happening and why it is happening.

And also, why is variable `res` only assigned value `('a', 'l')` in the first iteration of `while` loop?  Why is it not assigned `('b', 'm')`, and then `('c', 'n')` in second and third iteration?

Comment: Can you write what the function iter() is?

Comment: It's a built-in @DZurico. It converts an iterable into an iterator.

Comment: so iters is always truthy, even when it is done, you need to re-write you loop conditional.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Problem

> But I am still struggling to understand what is happening and why it is happening.
>
> And also, why is variable `res` only assigned value `('a', 'l')` in the first 
>    iteration of `while` loop? `res` is always assigned an empty list `[]` 
>    afterwards. Why is it not assigned `('b', 'm')`, and then `('c', 'n')` in second 
>    and third iteration?

The reason the code you posted works in Python 2 while failing in Python 3, is because the built-in `map` returns an *iterator* in Python 3, rather than a list as it did in Python 2.

*Of course* this doesn't really explain much unless you know what an iterator is. Although I could go in-depth about what an iterator is exactly<sup>1</sup>, the important part of iterators to understand here, is that: ***An iterator can only be iterated over once***. Once you've iterated over an iterator once, it's *exhausted*. It's done. You can't use it anymore.<sup>2</sup>

When you iterate over the `iters` iterator in the list comprehension in your code, ***then `iters` is done and exhausted, and can no longer be used***. So essentially all the list comprehension:

```
[next(i) for i in iters]
```

does is *grab the first item from each iterator* in `iters` (which are `'a'` and `'l'`), and then store those in a list. On the next iteration of your `while` loop, `iters` can no longer be used, *its empty*. So empty list are `yield`ed. That's why in the first list `yield`ed you see `'a'` and `'l'`, while other subsequent list are empty.

Lastly, the reason you're code degrades into an infinite loop, is because of the fact that an iterator object - even one that's been exhausted - will evaluate to `True` in a boolean context:

```
>>> it = map(str, [1, 2])
>>> next(it)
'1'
>>> next(it)
'2'
>>> # The `it` iterator is exhausted
>>> next(it)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    next(it)
StopIteration
>>> bool(it) # but it still evaluates to `True` in a boolean context
True
>>>
```

### Solution

The simplest solution to this problem is to cast the iterator returned by `map` into a list, since `list` objects support being iterated over multiple times:

```
>>> def custom_zip(*args):
    iters = list(map(iter, args))
    while iters:
        yield tuple([next(it) for it in iters])


>>> list(custom_zip('abc', [1, 2, 3]))
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
>>> list(custom_zip('def', [4, 5, 6]))
[('d', 4), ('e', 5), ('f', 6)]
>>> list(custom_zip([1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 9], [1, 8, 27]))
[(1, 1, 1), (2, 4, 8), (3, 9, 27)]
>>>
```

As @Chris_Rands also noted, although the above code works, a more idiomatic way to implement a custom `zip` function in Python 3+ would be:

```
def custom_zip(*args):
    return map(lambda *x: x, *args)
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>As a side note, if you would like to understand what an iterator is in-depth, see the question [*What exactly are Python's iterator, iterable, and iteration protocols?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-pythons-iterator-iterable-and-iteration-protocols#9884259)</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>For a more complete look into why exhausted iterators evaluate to `True`, see the question [*How can I get generators/iterators to evaluate as False when exhausted?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976269/how-can-i-get-generators-iterators-to-evaluate-as-false-when-exhausted)</sub>

Comment: Nice explanation but I think the simplest solution, if they just want to re-create `zip` in Py 3 with `map()` is `list(map(lambda *x: x, 'abc', [1, 2, 3]))`

Comment: Also relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976269/how-can-i-get-generators-iterators-to-evaluate-as-false-when-exhausted

Comment: Notice I said the _"simplest solution to **this** problem"_ ;-) But yes, kidding aside, I agree, your method is cleaner for Python 3. I'll add it in. And thanks for the link, I'll also incorporate that in.

Comment: One point to note though @Chris_Rands, is that your code returns a list rather than an iterator. This can be a problem for big list. So instead, it would probably be best to simply return the map iterator to the caller, and let them decide what to do with it.

Comment: Yes, wrapping in `list()` was just for illustration, BTW I think this will also work in Python 2 *if* the arguments are all the same length

Comment: Well yeah, that's kinda why I didn't want to include Python 2 @Chris_Rands. Rather than stopping at the shortest argument like the normal `zip` function, it simply uses `None` (which is like `itertools.izip_longest`.)

Comment: Great explanation! I did not know about the truthiness of iterators.

Comment: Thanks@Ajax, I appreciate the support :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
def myzip(*args):
    iters = list(map(iter,args))
    while iters :
        res = [next(i) for i in iters]
        print(res)
        yield tuple(res)

print (list(myzip('abc', '1mnop','yada')))
```

Output

```
['a', '1', 'y']
['b', 'm', 'a']
['c', 'n', 'd']
[('a', '1', 'y'), ('b', 'm', 'a'), ('c', 'n', 'd')]
```

Reason as provided by Christian Dean.

Answer (score 0):

the reason the code you posted works in Python 2 but mot in Python 3, is because the built-in map returns an iterator in Python 3, but returns a list in Python 2.

Comment: You can be more explanatory in your example, may be add a little code to explain the returned values and the major cause of difference in output.

Answer (score 0):

The iterator object only support next() or for ... statement.
You can reference it from here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator

If you want output as [('a','l'), ('b','m'), ...] you should not write the code like that.

By the way, please check if this is what you want:

```
def myzip(*args):
    iters = map(iter, args)
    while iters:
        res = [i for i in next(iters)]
        yield tuple(res)

list(myzip('abc', '1mnop'))
```

And the output would be:

```
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('1', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p')]
```